# System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges throws exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I get the following exception when I try and run my MVC web app with EF 6, on the following line of Code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<LiquorContext>(new LiquorContextInitializer()); //exception happens here
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

*The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1' threw an exception.*

I initially started developing this app on my laptop, Running VS2013 and SQL 2008 R2, and had no problems.  I copied the project over to my desktop PC, running VS2013 and SQL 2012 Developer Edition, and this is when this started happening.

Here is my connection string from the web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="LiquorContext" connectionString="Data Source=ANDREW-PC\SQL2012;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LiquorDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Make sure your class library is the same on both projects. If not, then make them the same. Uninstall and reinstall entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

Below action need to verify

1. installation EF properly on destination m/c
2. enable migration, add migration and update DB script properly
3. compare your configure EF settings

Comment: I have used Nuget to update all my relevant packages.  How do I enable the Migration, or add it?